# QGIS - some edit feature options disabled in vector layer

Tags: qgis, vector, editing

I created a new vector layer in QGIS, saving as I went along and then I saved the project and logged out.  When I went back into the project, I wanted to add some more features to the same layer, so selected the toggle editing icon and highlighted the vector layer.  However, not all the options are displaying for me - I can select 'move features' or 'node tool' but can't select the 'add feature' option, for instance.

I took a look at this question which seems to be a similar issue: [After re-open of old project file, several layer selections no longer available](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/27168/after-re-open-of-old-project-file-several-layer-selections-no-longer-available)

As suggested, I tried switching on and off the layers and exiting QGIS again, but so far I can't resolve the issue.

I am relatively new to QGIS.

Comment: Could you edit the layer outside your project? I.e. load the layer itself into QGIS and see if you can add features.

Comment: Thanks, Joseph - I tried that.  I'm now worried that the file might be corrupt somehow.  I just went into the layer folder and I can now see that one of the file extensions looks a bit strange - it is formatted [filename]_packed.dbf  The other extensions are fine .prj, .qpj, .shp and .shx.  Has anyone come across this before, and is there a way to rectify it?

Comment: I think the following link covers this: [How to avoid creating corrupt Shapefiles during Editing?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/58101/how-to-avoid-creating-corrupt-shapefiles-during-editing). Hopefully you have made backups =)

Comment: OK, would you believe, I managed to resolve this simply by deleting '_packed' from the file name.  This was among the suggestions in the link you sent me, Joseph, so thanks for that - much appreciated! Good point re: back-ups, I had made one but it also included the corrupt user name, so I will go and back this up straight away.

Comment: Haha glad you got it resolved! And your most welcome buddy! You should post what you did as an **answer**, the suggestion you followed in the link was posted as a **comment** and the user who posted it hasn't been active for a while so I think it might be best for you to post it which could help others with similar problems :)

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that one of the files had got corrupted.  When I went into the layer folder, one of the file extensions was ending in [filename]_packed.dbf rather than just [filename].dbf

I managed to resolve this simply by deleting '_packed' from the file name.